# nestjs return undefined in Public Guards

Tags: node.js, authorization, nestjs, guard

I follow this link [https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally](http://Hello%20friends%20I%20follow%20this%20link%20https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#enable-authentication-globally%20%20I%20went%20ahead%20and%20create%20a%20public%20guard%20%20But%20it%20does%20not%20recognize%20my%20requests%20when%20I%20put%20@Public%20on%20top%20of%20any%20controller%20%20I%20want%20to%20detect%20usser%20is%20logged%20on%20public%20routes)

I went ahead and create a public guard

But it does not recognize my requests when I put @Public on top of any method

and returns undefined !

I want to detect usser is logged on public routes

**JwtAuthGuard**

```
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }
    return super.canActivate(context);
  }
}
```

**Public Decorator**

```
export const IS_PUBLIC_KEY = 'isPublic';
export const Public = () => SetMetadata(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, true);
```

**Sample controller**

```
@Public()
@Get()
async find(@LoginUser() user: User): Promise<any> {
    console.log(user);
    // the user is undefined even after login
}
```

Comment: What returns `underfined`? Can you show code? What does this public guard do?

Comment: The task of this guard is to check the existence of the jwt token
without @Public Decorater its Work but when When I put it on top of any method it does not recognize the user

Comment: @JayMcDoniel

I edited the question and added some codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the route to be public and have a clause in your guard that says "if the route is public return true before attempting a login". If you want to login regardless of if the route is public or not, and *then* return ture at all times you can do something like

```js
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
    super();
  }

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const canAct = await (super.canActivate(context) as Promise<boolean>)
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    return isPublic ?? canAct;
  }
}
```

This will now have passport attempt a login from the get-go. So long as you don't throw an error in the `valdiate` method, or anything the `validate` method calls, everything should proceed as Passport does the  login, check if the route is public, and return true if so, return if the login was successful if the route is not public.

Answer (score 0):

write this:

```
constructor(@Inject(Reflector) private reflector: Reflector){
    super();
}
```

Comment: Please expand on your answer. Clarify the what does the code does.